# How to rewrite application using SQL to NoSQL datastore of google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have web application which using spring wicket and sql-processor (similar to mybatis) which works with databases. Now I want to try deploy this application to google app engine. I read that GAE support Google Cloud SQL which isnt free so I dont want use it and App Engine Datastore. So I need to use second one. Is there some tutorial how rewrite my database tier which now use SQL to NoSQL datastore of GAE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly - no.

This is similar to asking: my code is written in Java, is there a tutorial how to rewrite it in C? (I purposely said migrating from more-features language to less-features language)

SQL and NoSQL are quite different. The first obstacle you will hit is that NoSQL has quite less features: queries are simpler (no cross-table queries, no JOINs) and transactions are limited (must be within entity group or XG, which are limited to spanning five entities).

The result of all this is that NoSQL requires a different approach to coding: access-optimized approach vs structure-optimized approach. In simpler words: you write code to access data in as few operations as possible. This leads to de-normalized databases, i.e. writing same data in multiple places to get faster to it.

So, the only way is to earn about Datastore and then migrate code by hand. Or finding someone who knows datastore NoSQL and would do the work for you.

Comment: but there is lot of tutorial how rewrite java code to C.